# Why I get Error in installing python-weka-wrapper3 although Visual C++ 14.0 is installed

Tags: python, visual-c++, installation, weka

I tried to:

```
pip install python-weka-wrapper3
```

I installed `Visual C++ 14.0` from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017). In addition I used the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge implicit
```

in CMD. I use Windows 7.

And after rebooting still getting:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-to
ols

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for javabridge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sidestep the compilation of *javabridge* by downloading a wheel file instead ([from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#javabridge)). See the full instructions for anaconda users on Windows [here](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/install.html#windows-using-anaconda).